# css stylesheet not working properly via php if conditional statement

Tags: php, css, if-statement

I'm processing a CSS stylesheet by including the following at the top of my header:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='/index'){ ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/extensions/toastr.min.css">
<?php } ?>
```

This css sheet is to set a toast message.

The problem here is that, the stylesheet is displayed but then the toast doesn't load properly, but if I process the stylesheet without the php if statement, the toast loads perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by toast loading properly?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Are you sure the URL of `toastr.min.css` is correct?

Comment: It works fine if its called without the php if statment, and the toast message attached to this css sheet displays properly on page load, but when called on true via the if statement the toast messages displays but very awful @Barmar

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would be different depending on the `if` statement.

Comment: Its weird, at the same time it just started responding now after clearing cache.

Comment: I suspect the problem was unrelated to the `if` statement, you just had a bad version of something cached.

Comment: Well thanks for trying atleast